# How to programmatically *remove* a Google Sheets menu item in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, menu

Apps Script folks, how do I programmatically *remove* a custom menu item in Google Sheets from Apps Script.  There are enough ways to add items but I see nothing for removing.  Seems like this is a major API omission?  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are no methods for removing menu items.

An alternative approach is building a new menu and using it to replace the existing menu. Note, *the replacement menu must have the same name as the existing menu*, otherwise an additional menu will be added.

The following example will initially create a menu with 1 item, wait 5 seconds, then replace it with another menu with one more item and then repeat until there's a menu with 5 items.

```
function onOpen() {
  for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    addMenu(i);
    Utilities.sleep(5000);
  }
}

function addMenu(numItems) {
  var menu = SpreadsheetApp.getUi().createMenu('Test Menu');
  for (var i = 0; i < numItems; i++) {
    menu.addItem('Entry ' + i, 'nullFunc');
  }
  menu.addToUi();
}

function nullFunc() {}
```