# How to remove an Extensions submenu item in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, menu, add-on

I am using the following code in my Apps Script Editor Add-On to add a menu item:

```
function onInstall(e) {
  onOpen();
}

function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
  ui
  .createAddonMenu()
  .addItem("Open Search Sidebar", "createAndShowSidebarContent")
  .addToUi();
}
```

During development, we were using the features of the add-on in a shared Google Sheet by just adding the code manually, via Extensions --> Apps Script.

Running that code, while it was bound to Sheet,  added a sub-menu item under Extensions as:

> sheet-name --> Open Search Sidebar

Now that I have the add-on approved and in Google Workspace Marketplace, I removed the bound code from the Sheet and installed the Add-On. When run as an Add-On, a second sub-menu item is added to Extensions as:

> addon-name --> Open Search Sidebar

My question is how do I get rid of the  first menu item that was created before it was an Add-On: "sheet-name --> Open Search Sidebar"?

[ The only SO answer that I found for removing menu items is this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60179904/1978840 which is not viable for the Extensions menu. ]

Answer (score 0):

I think that the correct answer is to remove the Apps Script code for the Google Sheet and then have a bit of patience and the menu item will go away!

That's what happened 2 days after I installed the Add-On.

Comment: That looks to be [hacky](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/hacky). By one side, you should not remove the Apps Script project as this will make the add-on to stop working, if by remove you mean just delete the code but keep the project,  later when you want to update your add-on you will have to add the code again.

Comment: You would need to have the add-on project separate from the Sheet and then you can freely delete the script that's bound to the sheet

Comment: @Rubén I'm talking about the Apps Script code that you see when you select "Extensions --> Apps Script" This is the code that I used during development and I no longer need or want to have it any more. Also, the add-on does not need this code.

Comment: @Ihopethisishelpfultoyou The add-on project IS separate from the Sheet and I had already deleted the script bound to the sheet. But I could not delete the menu item that the bound script created. But after I waited 2 days, the menu item went away.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @JohnPankowicz. It looks that the question hasn't enough details as apparently the you have two projects involved in this issue. You could edit the question to add more details so other could reproduce the same behavior or just add the details mentioned in the comment to the answer.